# convert postgresql db into Microsoft Access db with python

Tags: python, postgresql, ms-access

How to convert a existing postgresql db into a Microsoft Access db with python?

I want to convert my postgresql db into a Microsoft Access db.
There are many possible solutions, like transfer table by table and inside the tables row by row.

But which of the solution mide be the best in terms of performance?

Comment: Why? That is step backwards. Why not just set up linked tables in Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install the ODBC driver and *link* the tables from PostgreSQL
2. Mark the link tables and choose *Convert to local table*
3. (Optional) Go to Database Tools, Access Database, and select to *split* the database to have the tables in an external Access database